# How to translate Summernote editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I found that Summernote plugin, has a lot of js files with translations. But how to apply them? I already included them to my page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to include translation source [file](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/tree/develop/src/lang) on your page and then after initializing the summernote editor, set the language.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(".summernote").summernote({
    toolbar: [.....],
    lang: "da-DK"
  });
</script>
```

EDIT:

You can use CDN also if you wish

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/lang/summernote-da-DK.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you add an example translation?

Answer (score 10):

Example:

File #1 (js) Save as "summernote-ES.js" :

```
  (function ($) {
  $.extend($.summernote.lang, {
    'es-ES': {
      font: {
        bold: 'Negrita',
```

bla, bla, bla (this file has 150 lines)
[file complete](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/lang/summernote-es-ES.js)

File #2 (html) index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/theme/monokai.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/3.20.0/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/formatting.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="summernote.css">
<script src="summernote.js"></script>
<script src="[your-url]/summernote-ES.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.summernote').summernote({ lang: 'es-ES' }); 
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.18/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
<script src="~js/lang/summernote-de-DE.js"></script>

$('textarea#des-summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: '',
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 100,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'clear']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
        ],
        lang: 'de-DE',
    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/tree/develop/lang

You can get language file from above link
for me I copy summernote-de-DE.js file and create that file to my directory
Note: Make sure "summernote-de-DE.js" file at last

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Saddam please add some explanation for the provided code.